# please explain why the valueOf method is important here and are there any other alternatives than using valueOf()?

Tags: java, value-of

```
public static String obify(String v) {
    //String v = "AEIOU";
    String result = "";
    for(int i=0; i<v.length();i++) {
        String x = String.valueOf(v.charAt(i));

        //if a character in the string is an age,i,o,u, or y,
        // then we insert a "OB" infront of the character.
        // So if your string was ajp, then the output should
        // be obajb. My question is why is the valueof method
        // here important, are there any other alternatives?
            
        if(x.equals("A")|| x.equals("E")|| x.equals("I")|| x.equals("O")|| x.equals("U")|| x.equals("Y")) {       
            result = result + "OB" + x;      
        }  
        else {
            result +=x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could also do v.substring(i, i + 1)

Answer (score 3):

[`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char)) is converting your char to a string. You don't need to do that. You can keep it as a char, and compare the char to other chars instead of to strings. Chars are single-quoted instead of double-quoted.

```
public static String obify(String v) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<v.length(); i++) {
        char ch = v.charAt(i);
            
        if (ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U' || ch=='Y') {          
            result += "OB" + ch;      
        } else {
            result += ch;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can make that more concise by instead of checking if your character is equal to one of those letters using `||`, you can check if it is present in a string.

```
    ...
    if ("AEIOUY".indexOf(ch) >= 0) {
        result += "OB" + ch;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this much more concisely with regex:

```
return v.replaceAll("[AEIOUY]", "OB$0");
```

Comment: No need for a capture group: `v.replaceAll("[AEIOUY]", "OB$0")`

Answer (score 0):

The v.charAt() methods a 'char' value and you are using the String.valueOf method to convert a 'char' value into a 'string'.
Please refer to the java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-). I think this would answer your question.

As for alternatives, there are so many, but for your scenario, using a valueOf is perfectly okay, but actually the valueOf method is not required if you refactor it as follows;

```
public static String obify(String v) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
        char charValue = v.charAt(i);
        switch (charValue) {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'Y':
                result.append("OB").append(charValue);
                break;
            default:
                result.append(charValue);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Note that concatenation of string is also not recommended, instead in the code snippet above a "StringBuilder" is used. Also, the if statement has been replaced by a switch.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank that makes sense, since the for loop is going though a char each iteration, we want to convert it to a string. Makes sense. Thank you